# How to create Dictionary [Key : value] in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary

I have a input elements in html with two important attributes: id, and parentElementId.

I want to create a map/dictionary that looks like this: "id : parentElementId".

```
var parent = $(".people-autocomplete").map( function(){ return $(this).attr('id')+':'+$(this).attr('parent'); }).get() ;
```

for know I'm putting the values into a string, which I parse later on in the code. I presume there is a more elegant solution than this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use an object:

```
var obj = {};
$(".people-autocomplete").each(function() {
    obj[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).attr('parent');
});
```

You can then access the parent of a specific `id`:

```
var parent = obj.idName;
```

or through a string:

```
var idStr = 'idName';
var parent = obj[idStr];
```

And you can loop through:

```
for (idStr in obj) {
    var parent = obj[idStr];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON` object for this purpose, You are confusing the usage of `.map()` in Jquery with `map` of other languages.

You can create a Json object like,

```
var xObj = {};
xObj.id = 'parentElemtnId';

alert(JSON.stringify(xObj)); // { id : 'parentElementId' }
```

Comment: but the problem is I want to iterate through all the elements that are ".people-autocomplete"